# What's the best way to listen for epoch updates?

Tags: account, validator, stake, geyser, epoch

I want to generate a proof from the epoch vote accounts to the Epoch Accounts hash, so I was thinking of listening to epoch updates and then generating a proof. I'm aware that bank has a `warp_from_parent()` & a `new_from_parent()` where the epoch accounts hash and epoch stakes are updated. Now what would be the best way to subscribe to this notification? Preferrably through geyser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options available:

- use the `slotSubscribe` or `slotUpdatesSubscribe` websocket endpoints to find out when the slot for the new epoch has started. Once you notice that you can fetch all of the accounts you want to calculate the hash
- with geyser, you can use the `update_slot_status` notification to see when the new epoch has begun (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8143fc3f4ae1fe89a7c362639c39ba7b68d92d5c/geyser-plugin-interface/src/geyser_plugin_interface.rs#L390) -- I'm not sure if it will also send the new state of all vote accounts, but if it does, you'll also need to handle `update_account` for all the accounts owned by the vote program (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8143fc3f4ae1fe89a7c362639c39ba7b68d92d5c/geyser-plugin-interface/src/geyser_plugin_interface.rs#L374)

Comment: This just updates the slots though, how do we know if it's the epoch boundary?

Comment: The epoch boundaries are well known slot numbers. Since each epoch is 432,000 slots, if the slot number is divisible by 432,000, then it's at the boundary. Since that slot might get skipped, however, it might not be exactly divisible by 432,000. For example, if slot 432,000 is skipped, you'll need to see if it's 432,001, 432,002, etc

Comment: got it, thanks!. I made a new pubsub method to subscribe to epoch updates. When i try to run `/target/release/solana-test-validator` , i get a `Method not found` error when i try to subscribe to my new method. I'm not sure what the cause might be but here's the link to my branch:

https://github.com/tinydancer-io/solana-1.18/tree/epoch-pubsub

Comment: You've got it all done right, but the client is using the name `"epochUpdatesSubscribe"` instead of `"epochsUpdatesSubscribe"`

Comment: well so this resolved, but the test binary that i built to test this pubsub api just blocks without logging any output, which seems like the stream is empty. Do we know of any way to trigger an epoch through the solana test validator?

Comment: You can use the `--slots-per-epoch` flag to have epochs that last 32 slots, then you'll get an update pretty often. There's no remote way to move the clock though

Comment: Is the epoch accounts hash enabled in the test-validator or is it disabled by default? Since my logic checks that an optimistically confirmed bank has the EAH calculation enabled using `is_enabled_this_epoch()` fn

Comment: Typically everything is enabled by default when you start a new test validator, but you can double check in the source code: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/5562d8dae9b01d2f6299869172bbda18d0ed77fe/sdk/src/feature_set.rs#L533